# Он старался оглушить себя ее постельными безумствами, хотя бы затем, чтобы не потерять навыков в любви

Tags: синтаксис

*Он старался оглушить себя ее постельными безумствами, **хотя бы затем**, чтобы не потерять навыков в любви.*

Как синтаксически называется то, что выделено запятыми?

Спасибо!

Comment: Пояснительный оборот, может быть.

Answer (score 2):

Могу предположить следующий вариант:

(1) Он старался оглушить себя ее постельными безумствами хотя бы затем, чтобы не потерять навыков в любви (расчленение союза).

(2) Он старался оглушить себя ее постельными безумствами, хотя бы затем чтобы не потерять навыков в любви.

ХОТЯ БЫ - это частица, которая не отделяется от союза запятой, значение ограничения и уступки.

Из словаря: ХОТЯ БЫ - частица, с частицей бы.  Спойте х. бы немножко. Съешьте х. бы кусочек. Не люблю, когда опаздывают х. бы на пять минут. Не давала никому своих книг, х. бы на время.

Answer (score 1):

> *Он старался оглушить себя ее постельными безумствами, **хотя бы затем**, чтобы не потерять навыков в любви.*
>
> Как синтаксически называется то, что выделено запятыми?

По-моему, **присоединительная конструкция**, распространённая придаточным.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь: К условиям расчленения сложного союза относятся:

2)      наличие перед союзом усилительных, ограничительных и других частиц, например: Наташа в эту зиму в первый раз начала серьезно петь и в особенности оттого, что Денисов восторгался ее пением (Л. Толстой); Водитель как раз для того, чтобы люди схлынули, застопорил машину против калитки (Фадеев); Стоит ли отказываться от трудного дела только потому, что оно трудное? (Крымов);

Аналогично: Он старался оглушить себя ее постельными безумствами хотя бы затем, чтобы не потерять навыков в любви